Animating the path of a moving object placed at the top of a circular surface and moving into free fall
I was trying to do an animation of an object sliding on a circular surface.
It starts at the top, moves to the right, loses contact, then proceeds to fall freely.
I want to know if there is a way to calculate the trajectory for this object?
I think we can find the angle at which it loses contact and conditionally animate before "as a point moving along a circle" and afterwards as "a free fall motion".
Also, I think it's important to know the speed of the object so I can animate correctly, maybe animate based on time and find the position that way.
I want to define the relations and make it as flexible as possible because I also want to play and put the circle in motion next, e.g. make the circle rotate to the right or to the left and see what happens; without re-writing all the other relations; and that might be in conflict with my idea of animating with the condition on which the contact between the circle and object is lost.

By "sliding through a circle" are you referring to moving on the top of a circular surface (like atop a roller coaster)?

@BobD I think that's the only reasonable way to interpret "on top of a circle" -- I've edited the question accordingly. Ofc, OP should clarify if he meant something else.

Yes, the question is edited with that fix, thanks.

@Amit What seems "reasonable" to one person may not be to another.

@BobD I agree! After all, our ability to communicate is based on the capacity to reasonably interpret what someone else said/wrote. Here, I felt confident enough that I understood what the OP meant, that's all :)

@Amit “reasonably interpret” would work well  if it were not for English being a second, third, etc. language for many contributors on this site.

@BobD I don't want to get into a long discussion here about that, but just let me clarify, when I wrote "I think the only reasonable way to interpret...", the emphasis is definitely on the I -- it wasn't a criticism towards you or anyone else for being more cautious with regards to figuring out what the OP meant.

@Amit I didn’t think it was a criticism of me. But having 6+ yrs on this site I have found it better to seek clarification in comments than waste time developing  answers that wind up not applying. No further discussion is needed.

The Animation

The blue ball is rolling without friction on the circular surface. It loses contact with the surface when the contact force between the ball and the surface becomes zero. At this point, the ball moves like a "projectile" (parabolic shape) .
to do the Animation you need the equation of motion and the contact  force between the ball and the surface.

I used this equation of motion
$$\ddot\varphi-\frac{g}{r}\,\sin(\varphi)=0$$
and the contact force
$$N=m\,(g\,\cos(\varphi)-\dot\varphi^2)$$
start the simulation with the Initial conditions $~\varphi(0)=0.044~,\dot\varphi (0)=0$
and stop the simulation if $~N \le 0~$
the ball position is
$$x=r\,\sin(\varphi(t))\quad,y=r\,\cos(\varphi(t))$$
If the contact force is zero the trajectory of the ball is
$$x=x_0+v\,\cos(\alpha)\,t\quad,
y=y_0+v\,\sin(\alpha)\,t-\frac{g\,t^2}{2}$$
where $~v=r\,\dot\varphi_{t=t_c}~$
where r is the circle radius, m ist the ball mass
the animation is done with this  program
https://ezgif.com/maker

thanks, what is the relation betwen time and the position of the object? also I think in free fall it does not continue in a straight line

From the solution of the equation of motion you obtain $~\varphi(t)~$ the position of the mass is dependent on $~\varphi~$ .

Probably you are right, in “free fall “ the mass behave like a projectile.

The animation appears to show the ball falling into the surface after it enters free fall, which is of course physically impossible. The general behavior is right, but something is wrong with the exact positions.

@NuclearHoagie is right, and in fact, I think the previous animation was more faithful to what would really happen. The vertical distance between the point the ball loses contact and the bottom of the screen is too small anyway, but if it was larger, what we should see is that the path of the ball also curves downwards in a parabolic pattern. However, seeing it initially for a short time, flying off in what's close to a straight tangent is in fact the right thing to expect. (and it was that way before the edit).

@Amit The animation is now realistic . this is because the speed  of the ball is higher as bevor, so there is no collision anymore . The equation that I worte are correct –
Eli
Commented 12 mins
